# Vote early, vote often

Tags: discussion

**We currently have far more users who have posted an answer or a question than [have ever voted](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/users?tab=voters)**, despite voting being easier and less time consuming than contributing a question/answer.

If we want this site to succeed, we should give more emphasis to voting as often as we can (both on questions and answers), because:

- It helps to surface the best content and gives new visitors an indication of the quality of the content they are looking at.
- It encourages users who are posting (or considering posting) their first few answers to the site by rewarding their time spent doing so.
- It encourages multiple answers to a question. [With EE](https://expressionengine.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20/expressionengine-and-the-case-of-two-right-answers) as with everything [TMTOWTDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There's_more_than_one_way_to_do_it) applies in spades. Second/third/fourth answers often bring useful input or different approaches that enrich the overall quality of the site no end.
- Whilst we're in beta, all privileges have a lower threshold than after launch. More votes means more users with the privileges for stuff like moderation and tag wiki edits, which in turn means that workload can be spread more evenly makinf for better/faster moderation + approval of edits etc.

Use your conscience/judgement of course - I'm not advocating voting just for the sake of it, but **if a post is good, please vote for it**  (particularly on questions, as these are often from newer users). It's easy to do and you'll be helping to make this a better place.

So to make this into a question rather than just an observation and an exhortation: **how do we communicate the importance of voting and encourage people to do it?**

*PS You might not know that...*

- *You can vote up to 40 times per day*
- *You can upvote more than one answer to a question*
- *<strike>Voting makes you more attractive to the opposite sex</strike>*

Comment: +1 and +1 vote!

Comment: Definitely agree. For more on the vote early, vote often rationale [see this Stack Exchange Blog Post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/).

Comment: Couldn't agree more.

Comment: I would have voted this up just for the title. :) Since it's an awesome discussion point, i'm even gladder to vote on it!

Answer (score 2):

This is still an important question. We need more participation in voting during the founding stages of this site! According to the [Area 51 summary](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/46387/expressionengine) of this site, in spite of good participation in Q&A, we are not on target in terms of avid users.

[image: EE Area 51 Stats]

No one is advocating mindless up-voting, but there are plenty of good questions and answers out there. So when you are browsing the site and see a good post, cast your vote!

As Tom already mentioned, **voting is a really important form of participation** because:

- It helps identify the best answers
- It encourages users who are adding value to the site
- It establishes a solid user-base to carry us into launch

For more on why voting matters, see this [Stack Exchange blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/)

Answer (score -2):

I tried to vote this down, as I think people should use the tool as it makes sense to them. Can't though, as I don't have enough 'rep' (125).  More games / hoops to jump through to use this site. Really have to be of a hardcore engineer / developer mindset to find this site accessible or user friendly. Seriously, every time I try something new on SE, some new arbitrary* rule is in place stopping me from doing so.

*I know these are not completely arbitrary, but rather in place to try and shape the quality of the content. But it is so heavy handed and pervasive, it keeps average people away.

Comment: So, within that framework (which I find as arbitrary as you at times) I'm advocating for people who _can_ to upvote contributions by people like you whose current rep prevents them from contributing as much as they want to, as, given that we can't change the rules, that seems to me the best way to get past that frustration. If more people voted, more of the time, those rule would be less of an obstruction (I hope).

Comment: Fully agree that people should use the tool as makes sense to them, _But... while we're trying to get this baby off the ground participation is key_. Voting on good questions and answers is a big part of that. [See this answer](http://meta.expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/94/22) from the Director of Community Development.

Comment: I don't know @ira42. Most of these are just suggestions. As far as hoops: I do understand what you are saying though, currently this is the best platform, for free I might add, that provides the quickest EE answers out there. Answers to almost any kind of question you may have as long as it relates to ExpressionEngine. The pros definitely out weigh the cons in my opinion if you compare it to something like the new "$50+ a month service" which EL provides and chances are you can only get answers about EE core there and nothing else (assumption as I haven't tried it.) [cont]

Comment: [cont] At the end of the day we are in someone elses house and sometimes we just have to eat the food they make even if we don't like it :)